# how to detect when an Android activity starts and ends

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Activity Life Cycle - difference between onPause() and OnStop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-difference-between-onpause-and-onstop)

my question is about if it is possible to detect when an Android activity starts/ends.

The idea would be to have a listener o callback method to execute some code during those events, but I can't find anyone :_(

Thank you very much in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the android [activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) life cycle. You have hooks available to do custom tasks during the various life cycle events.

Comment: thanks!! but I would like to do it externally. I mean, from a separate --control-- class in which I can control when an activity starts or ends

Comment: Why would you want to do that? There are probably more standard ways of achieving what you want to do, which would be more likely to get further help on.

Comment: I am creating instrumentation classes, so I need to track what is happening inside the application, but not using class intrusiveness (e.g. add code into an activity is not allowed, I have to control this activity from outside)